# Does Animal Crossing: City Folk still work over LAN?

Tags: nintendo-wii, animal-crossing-city-folk

I have one copy for my Wii, but now my girlfriend would like to play co-op with me on our Wii U. I dont really want to go out and buy a second copy if we can't play over LAN together now that WiiConnect24 is no longer on service.

Also, please don't recommend buying New Leaf. We already own it but want something we can play on the big screen.

Comment: Doesn't the console automatically try to look online when playing the games, themselves?

Connecting to a local area network (and be careful - if you google LAN it makes the assumption that your wanting to still use the internet) should always be possible, but the games are usually pre programmed to look to the official servers. If it is otherwise a separate feature (local play), this should work exactly as it always has.

Comment: @Timelord64 Given I only have one copy of the game, the ISO running on a single modded Wii, I can't tell one way or another. I was hoping someone with direct experience or source had the answer. I think what I'll do it borrow my friends Wii this weekend, which is also softmodded, and see if it works.

Comment: Your main problem is if your trying to get around security on the console, or otherwise breach its terms and conditions. Firstly, your going to have an uphill battle, and second, we are not allowed to give you advise for breaching those kind of things.

Comment: it does look like it has been confirmed to allow local network 2 player a couple of times over at Game FAQs. I would still make sure, unless you can get a good price.

Comment: @Timelord64 The main problem isn't a security breach, it's that I don't know if the title supports local network play, or if it only supports multiplayer via WFC/WC24.

Answer (score 1):

There is no local play. The only way to do this over LAN or Wifi is to hack your Wii.  It's relatively simple and the only way to get continued support for this discontinued product.

## 1. Hack your Wii with LetterBomb

https://please.hackmii.com/

> Instructions
>
> 1. On Computer: If there is a folder titled "private" on your SD card,
>      rename it to "privateold"
> 2. On Computer: Copy the "private" directory from the LetterBomb
>      download to the root of your SD card.
> 3. On Computer: Take your homebrew (preferably Hackmii Installer) and
>      put it in the ROOT of your SD card as "boot.elf". Note that you can
>      download the Hackmii Installer directly from the download link
>      provided above. You will be asked for U (American), E (Europe), J
>      (Japanese) or K (Korean).
> 4. Wii: Put your SD card in your Wii and turn it on.
> 5. Wii: Go into the Wii Message Board and navigate to "Today",
>      "Yesterday" or "Two days ago".
> 6. Wii: Click on the appropriate envelope, sit back and prepare for the
>      hacking glory.

## 2. Patch your game with Wiimmfi

https://wiiki.wii-homebrew.com/Wiimmfi_(en)/Patcher

You will need to check that link to get additional links and files. Here's a simplified version of what you'll be doing.

> **Patching disk images**
>
> You will need:
>
> - A (soft)modded Nintendo Wii
> - The Homebrew Channel and
> - A Custom IOS (cIOS) to change the way your Wii accesses data
> - USB Loader GX (or a different USB loader)
> - A USB storage device (eg. HDD, USB stick) formatted for use with USB    Loader GX
> - Wii Backup Manager or a different WBFS Manager.

Follow the directions and you'll be good to go. Make sure you follow all the steps. If you mess up the part with custom IOS you're going to brick your Wii. As long as you're paying attention and following the steps you'll be fine. It's literally one of the easiest consoles to hack.

Comment: Please don't rollback edits that make it harder to find the answer.  We're trying to keep the signal to noise ratio high, so removing parts that aren't relevant to answering the question don't belong.

Comment: Softmodding and ISO patching is no longer a necessity, thanks to the following guide: https://youtu.be/3CBSQ9Afqiw

Answer (score 0):

No, ACCF doesn't and has never worked over LAN.

Why not Wiimmfi? It has full support for ACCF.

Answer (score -2):

You can still play Animal Crossing city Folk or lets go to the City using the new WIIMMFI servers. They are private and created to replace the Nintendo WFC servers that closed down.
All you need is a patched copy of ACCF or download the patcher for ACCF from WIIMMFI. You can google to find out all you need.

Comment: This doesn't really answer the question...